# How to create a model from image data set and use that in Chainer?

Tags: android, opencv, chainer

I have just started working with Chainer.

I have the requirement as follow,
I want to create a mobile application in `android` where a user can capture an image on the road and the application should identify one or two particular objects from that image.
For example, let's say pedestrian signal or zebra crossing.

A user will take a picture on the road and from that image, I want to identify this two objects.

I have a set of 1000 images of a different kind of `pedestrian` signal all over the world. I want to create a model of that which can be used to after compare image which is taken from the mobile camera from my `android` application.

I have some knowledge of `cascade classifier` or `SVM classifier` for the object detection and used that in past.

Is this possible with `chainer` of other supported `tools` with `chainer`?

I have been searching and I do get other options like `OpenCV` and `caffe2`, but I really need to implement it with `chainer`.

Any help will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about object detection where your application will detect zebra crossing among other things. There is ChainerCV, like OpenCV which is used for object detection tasks using chainer modules.
Here's the link to ChainerCV docs (https://chainercv.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/)!
I can post the code if you want.
ChainerCV will use object detection neural network models like Single Shot Multibox Detector(SSD300)(https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/tree/master/examples/ssd/)!,Yolo(https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/tree/master/examples/yolo/)! for the task.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).